# a pointer-to-memeber is not valid for a managed class

Tags: c++-cli

I have a Windows Form in Visual Studio C++. (CLR)

In the header file, I declare void createThread()

```
private: 

  void createThread() {
            char buffer[1024];
            ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            while (true) {
                recv(connection, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                main.displayMessage(gcnew System::String(buffer));
            }
            ExitThread(0);
    }
```

Now, I want to call function createThread 
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)createThread, NULL, NULL, NULL)
After that I get this error:
a pointe-to-member is not valid for a managed class

I tried user thread library but not support. How can I fix??

Comment: It is not the only thing that's wrong with that function, never use a cast to stop the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.  The function must look [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `static` is required for a C++ class function.  Consider to create a System::Thread, it has no trouble calling a member function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this function is defined in a managed class. You need to use the managed [thread object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2), not unmanaged CreateThread.

This error exists for two reasons: First, it's a instance method, not a static method, so it would need to be called with an instance of this type, which there's no way to pass to CreateThread. Second, it's a managed object, and its methods do not trivially convert to C-style raw function pointers.

Finally, a note about the language: C++/CLI is meant to act as a way to interface managed code (e.g., C#) with unmanaged C++. It's not intended as a primary development language. If you don't need to link managed and unmanaged code, you may want to consider switching to either C# or C++ for your application.